# $A^2$ is isomorphic to $A^{(\omega)}$, but not $A$

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, abelian-groups

Is there an abelian group $A$ with $A\not\cong A\oplus A\cong A\oplus A\oplus A\oplus\cdots$ (a direct sum of countably many copies of $A$)?

---

Edited to add: As no answers are forthcoming, does anyone know what happens if we allow arbitrary modules in place of abelian groups?

Comment: I don't remember very well: Are there classical examples of abelian groups with an isomorphism $A^n \simeq A^m$  for some $m \neq n >0$ without having $A^i \simeq A^j$ for all $i,j>0$ ?

Comment: There are examples of abelian groups that have two different decompositions into indecomposable summands $A\oplus B\cong\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}T_i$. If it were possible to do this with $A\cong B$ and all the $T_i$ isomorphic, then $A$ would have the property you ask for. Unfortunately the construction I found in the literature (by Corner) seems to lead in an essential way to the $T_i$ being non-isomorphic, but maybe there are other results in this direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but a construction that might give an answer.

I'll start by constructing a ring with several objects (a.k.a. preadditive
category) $\mathcal{C}$ by generators and relations, using similar ideas as in
Leavitt's ring with $R\not\cong R\oplus R\cong R\oplus R\oplus R$.

The objects $X_{1}, X_{2},\dots$ are indexed by the positive integers. For each
$m\leq n$ there are generators $\alpha_{n,m},\beta_{n,m}: X_{n}\to X_{m}$ and
$\gamma_{n,m},\delta_{n,m}:X_{m}\to X_{n}$.

The relations are designed to make
$$X_{n}\oplus X_{n}\cong X_{1}\oplus X_{2}\oplus\cdots\oplus X_{n}$$
for all $n$ once we close under finite direct sums. For example, for $n=3$
impose the relations that make the matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha_{3,1}&\beta_{3,1}\\\alpha_{3,2}&\beta_{3,2}\\\alpha_{3,3}&\beta_{3,3}
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma_{3,1}&\gamma_{3,2}&\gamma_{3,3}\\\delta_{3,1}&\delta_{3,2}&\delta_{3,3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
mutually inverse.

Now form a ring by adjoining a unit:
$$R=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\bigoplus_{m,n}\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X_{m},X_{n}).$$
For each $n$ let $e_{n}\in R$ be the idempotent corresponding to the
identity endomorphism of $X_{n}$, let $P_{n}=e_{n}R$ be the corresponding
projective right $R$-module, and let $P=\bigoplus_{n}P_{n}$.

Then $P_{n}\oplus P_{n}\cong P_{1}\oplus P_{2}\oplus\cdots\oplus P_{n}$ for each
$n$, so
\begin{align}
  P\oplus P&\cong (P_{1}\oplus P_{1})\oplus(P_{2}\oplus P_{2})\oplus(P_{3}\oplus
             P_{3})\oplus\cdots\\
  &\cong P_{1}\oplus (P_{1}\oplus P_{2})\oplus(P_{1}\oplus P_{2}\oplus
    P_{3})\oplus\cdots\\
  &\cong P^{(\omega)}
\end{align}

**Question 1.** Is $P\cong P\oplus P$?

Probably not, as there seems no obvious way to produce such an isomorphism.

If the answer to Question 1 is ``no'', then this answers the supplementary
question in the OP about modules.

As for abelian groups:

Clearly $R$ is countable.

**Question 2.** Is $R$ torsion free?

Probably, as there seems no obvious way to produce a torsion element.

**Question 3.** Is $R$ reduced?

Probably, as there seems no obvious way to produce a divisible element.

If the answers to Questions 2 and 3 are both ``yes'', then Corner's theorem
applies, and $R\cong\operatorname{End}(B)$ for some abelian group $B$.

Let $A_{n}=e_{n}(B)$ and $A=\bigoplus_{n}A_{n}$. Then
$$A\oplus A\cong A^{(\omega)}.$$

**Question 4.** Is $A\cong A\oplus A$?

I don't see any reason that it should have to be (note that $B$ is not uniquely
determined, so the answer to Question 4 might conceivably depend on the
particular choice of $B$).

Comment: I sent a sketch of this argument to Pace after he posted the original question, and promised to write it up and post it on MathOverflow when I got time. It seems to have taken me over a year. :-(

Comment: I believe that Pace, who is a far more skilful wielder of Bergman's Diamond Lemma than I am, knows how to answer some of the questions in my answer. I have made the answer community wiki, and would be happy for Pace or anybody else to add answers to my questions.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up! Using Bergman's Diamond Lemma, and especially Bergman's work in his two 1974 papers on coproducts that were published in TAMS, I feel like I have a good grasp on the ring $R$ and the monoid of isomorphism classes of finitely generated project modules.  So questions 2 and 3 are likely very doable.  However, I actually don't know how to approach showing $P\not\cong P\oplus P$, since $P$ is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 8):

This is a long comment responding to Simon Henry's [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428634/a2-is-isomorphic-to-a-omega-but-not-a#comment1102650_428634) in the comments to the original question.

The paper

A.L.S. Corner
On a conjecture of Pierce concerning direct decompositions of Abelian groups
Proc. Colloq. Abelian Groups, Tihany, 1963, Akadémiai Kiadó, Budapest (1964), pp. 43–48

provides an example of an abelian group $G$ such that $G\cong G\oplus G\oplus G$ and $G\not\cong G\oplus G$. I don't have access to the paper, so can't say whether Corner's example will solve the original question on this page. Here are the first two sentences of the [Math Review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=169905), written by R. S. Pierce:

*It is shown that for any positive integer $r$ there exists a countable torsion-free abelian group $G$ such that the direct sum of $m$ copies of $G$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of n copies of $G$ if and only if $m\equiv n\pmod{r}$. This remarkable result is obtained from the author's theorem on the existence of torsion-free groups having a prescribed countable, reduced, torsion-free endomorphism ring by constructing a ring with suitable properties.*

Comment: It won't solve the original question, since if $G\oplus G\cong G^{(\omega)}$ then $G\oplus G\oplus G\cong G^{(\omega)}\cong G\oplus G$. A positive example for the original question would have $G^m\cong G^n\cong G^{(\omega)}$ for any natural numbers $1<m<n$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard: Nice observation.

Comment: Thanks ! that indeed doesn't solve the original question - but the methods of the paper (according to the review you posted) of constructing an abelian group with prescribed endomorphisms ring seems like a fairly promising way to attack the problem...

Comment: The classic ring constructed by Leavitt, where we have (as right $R$-modules) $R\not\cong R^2\cong R^3$ should lead (by Corner's theorem) to an abelian group $A\not\cong A^2\cong A^3\cong A^4\cong\cdots$.  However, it isn't clear how one would get $A^{(\omega)}$ in the mix.